# Iterating through rows in dataframe to compare values to mean

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a large pandas dataframe, df, that includes crime statistics.  The columns are the category of crime (i.e., ARSON, ASSAULT, BAD CHECKS, GRAND THEFT, etc.).  The rows are the addresses where the crimes occurred.

The values in each cell are the number of times that each category of crime occurred at that address.

I need to write a function that iterates through each row of hte dataframe, compares the value to the MEAN number of crimes for each category, and then identifies only those addresses where the number of crimes exceeds the mean.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
crimeData = open("crimeData.csv")
df = pd.read_csv('crimeData.csv')
df = df.set_index ('Address')
mean = df.mean(axis=0)
#this gives me the mean for each Crime Category
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row > mean:
        print (index)
```

This is not working.  I get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Where am I going wrong?  How can I get it to a) identify which crime categories at each address occur more than the mean, and b) print the address along with the categories of crime that exceed the mean into a list?

Comment: You would have to be more specific: `where the number of crimes exceeds the mean for __all__ kind of crimes or for __any__ single crime`

Comment: I mean where the number of crimes in any given category (column) exceeds the mean for that category of crime.  In other words, if the number of ARSONS at Perry Avenue exceeds the mean number of ARSONS for all addresses, it should print   "Perry Avenue: ARSON"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going wrong where you say `row > mean`, this is comparing a series to a series and will return a series of True's and False's like `[True, False, False, True]`, it's erroring because you are asking if this is True or False and, of course, it can be both.

You could change you solution to something like:

```
...
mean = df.mean(0)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, list(df.columns[row > mean]))
```

However a better way would be to avoid iterating through the rows using iterrows.
You could do this relatively succinctly with something like:

```
...
df.set_index('Address', inplace=True)

df[df > df.mean(0)].notnull().apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df.columns[x]),axis=1)
```

The first part, `df[df > df.mean(0)]`, produces a dataframe replacing any values that are less than the mean with null.

The `.notnull()` part converts the null values to False and the values that are greater than the mean to True.

And then the apply part takes the column headers and applies the True or False values to them, removing the False column headers and then finally we concatenate the 'True' headers into a comma separated list per Address.

Comment: Nice solution! You can simplify it a bit: `df.gt(df.mean()).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df.columns[x]),axis=1)` or `(df > df.mean()).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df.columns[x]),axis=1)`, which is the same

Comment: I didn't know about the `.gt` method, very useful, thanks!

Comment: super elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can do this:

```
In [307]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (10,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [308]: df
Out[308]:
     a    b    c
0  755  250  450
1  142  810  460
2  814  268  204
3  534  546  837
4  373  246  266
5  158  775  560
6  451  503   85
7  988  265  703
8  164  503  239
9  578  188   76

In [309]: df.mean()
Out[309]:
a    495.7
b    435.4
c    388.0
dtype: float64

In [310]: df.gt(df.mean(), axis=1).any(1)
Out[310]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool

In [311]: df.loc[df.gt(df.mean(), axis=1).any(1)]
Out[311]:
     a    b    c
0  755  250  450
1  142  810  460
2  814  268  204
3  534  546  837
5  158  775  560
6  451  503   85
7  988  265  703
8  164  503  239
9  578  188   76
```

Comment: By using `any()`, you're saying that if _any_ category of crimes per address is greater than the mean number of _all_ category of crimes return `True` for that address for _all_ crimes, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Ok--when I apply this code and then print the new df, I end up with a much shortened df.  But it still isn't displaying what I want, which is simply a list of the Addresses (rows) along with the Crime Categories (columns) that exceeded the mean for that Crime Category.  The output I want would look something like: "Perry Avenue:  ASSAULT, ARSON, GRAND THEFT AUTO...." for each address that has a crime level exceeding the mean in its category.

Answer (score 2):

**crimeData.csv**

```
Address         Arson   Burglary  Assault  Murder
Lennon Rd       1       5         3        0
Starr Avenue    2       2         7        0
Harrison Lane   3       1         1        1
```

```
import pandas as pd

crimeData = open("crimeData.csv")
df = pd.read_csv('crimeData.csv')
df = df.set_index ('Address')
mean = df.mean()

# You can do the evaluation as simply as this...
exceeded = df[df > mean]
print(exceeded)

               Arson  Burglary  Assault  Murder
Address                                        
Lennon Rd        NaN       5.0      NaN     NaN
Starr Avenue     NaN       NaN      7.0     NaN
Harrison Lane    3.0       NaN      NaN     1.0
```

Following your comment...

```
for _, row in exceeded.iterrows():
    print(row.name, ":", " ".join(row.dropna().axes[0].values))
```

Comment: This is great!  Very close to what I need.  How can I now just print a list that has the address along with the name of the crime categories that exceed the mean.  Example:  Harrison Lane:  Arson, Murder

Comment: See the edit. Should do what you're after. You may want to adjust the formatting of the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

`mean` is an object of type `pandas.core.series.Series`. You are comparing another `Series` object, `row`, with `mean`, which is like saying "is this `Series` greater than this `Series`?" That's why the exception says the comparison is "ambiguous." Try something like this (done with mock data since none was provided):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [5,4,3,4,5], 'C': [6,7,8,9,10]})
mean = df.mean(axis = 0)

# This will give you all of the rows in `df` that are above the average for that crime statistic
for col in df.columns:
    higher_than_mean = df[df[col] > mean[col]][col]
```

An example of `higher_than_mean` for each column (crime statistic):

```
3    4
4    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
0    5
4    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
3     9
4    10
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I applied your code.  I ended up with a list of addresses and a corresponding set of integers (i.e., Perry Avenue    9).  I think this represents the number of crime categories at Perry Avenue that exceed the mean, correct?  So how can I get it to display the address with the actual crime categories that exceed the mean (i.e., the column titles)?

Answer (score 1):

***please note:***
this is a vectorize solution and doesn't require any loops.  @MaxU also provided a vectorized solution for identifying an address that may have exceeded the average of any category.

Consider the dataframe `crimeData` simulated below

```
crime_cats = ['ARSON', 'ASSAULT', 'BAD CHECKS', 'GRAND THEFT']
addresses = ['addr_{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]
crimeData = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(np.arange(5), size=(10, 4), p=(.6, .1, .1, .1, .1)),
    addresses, crime_cats
)

crimeData
```

[image]

By default, `crimeData.mean()` calculates the mean per column.  And by default, when we compare a dataframe to a series, it compares them row by row, aligning the series index with the column labels.  This is a dataframe that is one where crime at the specific address is greater that the crime type average, zero otherwise.

```
crime_gt_avg = (crimeData > crimeData.mean()).astype(np.uint8)
crime_gt_avg
```

[image]